# Case and accent insensitive 'like' comparison oracle without altering session on oracle

Tags: oracle, comparison, sql-like, diacritics, case-insensitive

I need to be able to do 'like' queries across several languages, so that a umlaut, a and A are treated the same and so on. I'm on 10gr2 of oracle and I can't alter the session.

I've been trying things like

```
nls_upper(col_name,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI') like nls_upper('%fur%','NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
```

but I'm not having any joy. Whatever I do, the result of nls_upper seems to preserve the umlauts on U for example.

Is there any function or operator I can use? Ideally, it would also convert the German eszett - that funny characted that looks like a B - into double S.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

So actually it seems like the best solution is to convert both string to US7ASCII, as that strips out all accents. So I can do:

upper(convert(col_name, 'US7ASCII')) like upper(convert('%okopla%','US7ASCII'))

The only wrinkle I've found is that the German eszett gets converted to ?. So I'm just going to look in my search term and if it contains a funny B, then I'm going to use Gary's NLS_UPPER ('große', 'NLS_SORT = XGerman'), otherwise I'll just do the conversion to ASCII. It's a little kludgy, but we only have to cover english, french and german, so I think it will be OK..

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you so much for this, all the documentation I found was with alter session. I don't know if this works for The German ß but it certainly does wonders for Spanish and Portuguese accents.

Comment: ã, õ and ñ are also converted to ?, so you have to replace them for spanish and portuguese as a work around.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#CIHJBFAD), you need to specify both NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC and NLS_SORT=XGERMAN_AI to be both umlaut and Eszett insensitive. I guess you must replace Eszetts by hand, with a `replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit the bill ?

```
select case when NLS_UPPER ('große', 'NLS_SORT = XGerman') 
                     like '%SS%' then 'YES' else 'no' end match
from dual;
```

If not, you have to elaborate the requirements a bit.

Comment: Thanks Gary - it's close... The problem is that if they enter fur, that's treated as differently to fur with an umlaut. I want to be able to say like '%fur%' and have that match both fur with and without an umlaut. That's why in my code above I'm trying to convert both into upper case, without accents, but insensitively. I guess what I really need to know is how to convert a string to just the base letters - I want fur and fur with an umlaut both to be rendered as FUR. I was hoping not to have to go to regex for performance reasons... Thanks for your help.. :-)

Comment: What if somebody enters "fuer"?

Comment: Also look at Oracle Text and synonyms (a mechanism that allows it to treak Coke and CocaCola as the same). It may be more effective for the underlying business case.